# pass a loop as parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

This is my stored procedure. It takes INT as input which is essentially an staff id.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMonthlyPayroll]
@StaffId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT        StaffId, Name, CNICNumber, Salary, BankAccountNumber,[dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, datename(month, GETDATE())) as TotalDaysWorked, [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, datename(month, GETDATE())) as TotalDaysWorked,
    (CONVERT([date],getdate())) AS PayrollDate,
    (CONVERT([date],dateadd(month,(-1),dateadd(month,datediff(month,(0),getdate())+(1),(0))))) AS PayrollFrom,
    (CONVERT([date],dateadd(day,(-1),dateadd(month,datediff(month,(0),getdate())+(1),(0))))) AS PayrollTo,
    (datename(month,getdate())) + ', ' + (datename(year,getdate())) AS PayrollPeriod,
    (Salary/[dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, datename(month,getdate()))) * [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, datename(month,getdate())) as GrossSalary,
              .10 as IncomeTaxFactor,
              ((Salary/[dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, datename(month,getdate()))) * [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, datename(month,getdate()))) - ((Salary/[dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, datename(month,getdate()))) * [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, datename(month,getdate())) * (.10)) as TotalNetSalary

FROM            Staff
where Staff.StaffId=@StaffId
END


GO
```

I want the same behavior but without manually providing input. I want it to fetch all existing staffId from staff table all by itslef with staffId still being the sole parameter. How do I do that? I have tried doing it by using a WHILE loop. But it

```
set @StaffId = select Staff.StaffId from Staff
```

is showing squiggly lines on `select`

Please help. I am using SQL server 2014.

Comment: Your query already  uses  Staff.StaffId table so just remove the WHERE condition if you want to loop through the whole table

Comment: Convert your Sproc to a Table Valued Function (which you should be doing anyway), then create a VIEW which does a CROSS APPLY of the original table with your TVF.

Comment: Yeah. That makes it a stupid question.

Comment: I do already have a ITVF for that. For performance reasons.

Comment: @Mihai despite it being as simple as that, I can still mark it an answer. Please post your comment as answer and you will have your score.

Comment: use,  select @StaffId =Staff.StaffId from Staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return all of the records from your `Staff` table every time and you want the exact same query to be executed every time, then you don't need a function at all, just create a View:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CurrentMonthPayroll
AS
    SELECT  StaffId, 
            Name, 
            CNICNumber, 
            Salary, 
            BankAccountNumber,
            [dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())) AS TotalWorkingDays, 
            [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())) AS TotalDaysWorked,
            (CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) AS PayrollDate,
            (CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,(-1),DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,(0),GETDATE())+(1),(0))))) AS PayrollFrom,
            (CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,(-1),DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,(0),GETDATE())+(1),(0))))) AS PayrollTo,
            (DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())) + ', ' + (DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())) AS PayrollPeriod,
            (Salary/[dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()))) * [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())) AS GrossSalary,
            .10 AS IncomeTaxFactor,
            ((Salary/[dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()))) * [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()))) - ((Salary/[dbo].[totalWorkingDaysScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()))) * [dbo].[totalDaysWorkedScalar](StaffId, DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())) * (.10)) AS TotalNetSalary
    FROM Staff
GO
```

If you want to `INSERT` these records into some other table, you can:

```
INSERT INTO PayrollTable
SELECT StaffId,
Name,
CNICNumber,
Salary,
BankAccountNumber,
TotalWorkingDays,
TotalDaysWorked,
PayrollDate,
PayrollFrom,
PayrollTo,
PayrollPeriod,
GrossSalary,
IncomeTaxFactor,
TotalNetSalary
FROM dbo.CurrentMonthPayroll
```

Answer (score 0):

I think process each staff with loop is not good performance.

you can modify you stored procedure to support process multiple staffs
For example, you can change the parameter @staffID to a varchar variable to get a string of combin multliple staffid with a delimiter

```
FROM   Staff
where Staff.StaffId=isnull(@StaffIds,Staff.StaffId)  --NULL is process all data
      or case when @StaffIds is null then 1 else 
charindex(','+convert(varchar,Staff.StaffId)+',',','+@StaffIds+',') end >0
```